# Countable subadditivity of Jordan content

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I$ be $n$-rectangle in $\mathbb R^n$. And $\mathcal D_{I}$ be collection of Jordan measurable sets contained in $I$ and let $c$ denotes Jordan content. If $A_n\in \mathcal D_I$ such that $A_n$ are mutually disjoint and  $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in \mathcal D_I$.

Will $c(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c(A_n)$?

Note: I am taking $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ also in $\mathcal D_I$ and then asking the question.

Comment: You need to add that the $A_n$ do not overlap. Otherwise the answer is a very obvious no. But with the added condition, the answer is yes.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes sorry added now. What can be proof of this fact

Answer (score 1):

Jordan measurable sets are also Lebesgue measurable, and the Jordan content is equal to the Lebesgue measure. Since Lebesgue measure is countably additive for non-overlapping sets, so must Jordan content be, provided that the union is Jordan measurable.

The only difference between the two is in what sets are measurable. Lebesgue measurability of the $A_i$ is enough to deduce Lebesgue measurability of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. But Jordan measurability fo the $A_i$ does not imply Jordan measurability of the union. However you've sidestepped that by making Jordan measurability of the union part of the assumptions.

Comment: Is there any other way then to go into theory of Lebesgue measurablity.

Comment: Lebesgue measurability is just a quick way of recognizing that the statement is indeed true. It can be proven directly from the definition of Jordan content. It is *almost* trivial to show that the infinite sum converges and is $\le$ the content of the union. Showing that it is not less than the content of the union is harder. For it, you essentially recreate the same proof from Lebesgue theory, except couched in the language of Jordan content.